# Show Correct Error Message Thrown from Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, error-handling

I'm working on a `Windows Forms` application. There is a lot of stuff happening in the constructor where I have several `try-catch` blocks. However as a final result I want to show the error message on the `form_shown` event. I'm not sure what's the correct way of doing this. I was thinking of making a string variable visible from all the form and then in every `try-catch` block to set different message that will be shown by calling showing the value of this string variable in the `form_shown` event where I want to do this.

But this doesn't seem very good approach. What I would prefer is some way to re throw the exception or something like that and handle it in the `form_shown` event. Which I think is closer to the correct error-handling approach.

Comment: Are the errors you're handling within the try-catch blocks legitimate failures, or something along the lines of validation errors? Sounds like you might be using Exceptions to handle your program flow. This might be a downstream problem from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are violating two important [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229060%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Do minimal work in the constructor. Constructors should not do much work other than to capture the constructor parameters. The cost of any other processing should be delayed until required.

And

> Do throw exceptions from instance constructors if appropriate.
>   Constructors should throw and handle exceptions like any method. Specifically, a constructor should not catch and hide any exceptions that it cannot handle.

So, to answer your question, if anything goes wrong in the constructor phase: show it immediately. It should mean that the object can't be constructed.

I don't know what this *lot of stuff* is that's happening in the constructor, but I'm pretty sure you should defer it to later moments, e.g. form load. But still: show exceptions where they occur.

Comment: Well, even though I don't have too much experience I do agree with you for everything. However due to bad architecture and some other things that's the way it is in this project so I try to make the best of it.

Comment: But I think you should be able to refactor code out of the constructor? Exceptions that are used for program flow (i.e. they are not only caught but also thrown) are harder to tackle and I think for now the best option would be to collect the exceptions themselves in a list and show their messages (also from any inner exceptions) when the form has loaded. But you should try to replace them by `if-then-else` logic.

Comment: For now the logic will stay in the constructor (manager decision). Other then that I will collect the exceptions as you offer.